# Retrieve key value based on another key value within the same row of a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter, array-column

I'm working with an indexed PHP array that resembles this structure:

```
$result =   Array(
  [0] => Array([storepickup_id] => 3[sku] => 691294[inventory] => 33[reserve] => )
  [1] => Array([storepickup_id] => 3[sku] => 692284[inventory] => 3[reserve] => )
  [2] => Array([storepickup_id] => 3[sku] => 692289[inventory] => 4[reserve] => )
  [3] => Array([storepickup_id] => 3[sku] => 693510[inventory] => 8[reserve] => )
  [4] => Array([storepickup_id] => 3[sku] => 150893[inventory] => 2[reserve] => )
  [5] => Array([storepickup_id] => 3[sku] => 150906[inventory] => 4[reserve] => )
)
```

I'm attempting to filter the above array with a prebuilt FOR EACH statement from that looks like this:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php
    echo "SKU: " . $_product->getSku();
    echo "INVENTORY: " . array_column($result, 'inventory', $_product->getSku());
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So if $_product-getSku() yields 691294, I would like to retrieve the corresponding 'inventory' value from the same index/row of the PHP array.

The above array_column within the FOR EACH did not work. I also attempted a function based on array_filter that failed to yield proper results:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
  <?php
  function my_function($item_values)
  {
      if ($item_values = $_product->getSku())
      {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
  $sku = $_product->getSku();
  print_r(array_filter($sku,"my_function"));
  ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Is there a better approach when working with multidimensional arrays such as above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a new array with index/key contain sku and column/value contain inventory from $result array.

```
$new_array = array_column($result, 'inventory', 'sku');
```

Then use the new array in the loop

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php
    echo "SKU: " . $_product->getSku();
    echo "INVENTORY: " . $new_array[$_product->getSku()];
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If $_product-getSku() yields 691294, Invetory will be 33

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, but in this case array_column function is called for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getIndex($needle, $haystack, $array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value) && $value[$haystack] == $needle)
              return $key;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Use like this:

```
$i = getIndex(691294, 'Sku', $array);
echo $array[$i]['inventory'];
```